# Issues with pinging Dhcp server and internet from Vlan 2

Tags: firewall, vlan

I am having issues with our new vlan's allowing access to the internet.

I have setup 2 vlans:
     Vlan 1: 10.0.1.210 255.255.255.0
     Vlan 2: 10.0.2.1 255.255.255.0

I have enabled Ip routing

Show ip route:

```
IP Route Entries

Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.
------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----
0.0.0.0/0          10.0.1.1        1    static               1          1
10.0.1.0/24        DEFAULT_VLAN    1    connected            1          0
10.0.2.0/24        Voice Vlan      2    connected            1          0
127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          0
127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            1          0
```

The reason I think my inter vlan communication isn't working is because I connect a laptop to untagged port 46 for vlan 2, and I statically assign my ip info as follows:

```
Ip: 10.0.1.251
Mask: 255.255.255.0
GW: 10.0.2.1
```

Dns: 10.0.1.252 ---> Current dns server which resides on vlan 1

I can ping 10.0.1.210, 10.0.1.128 ---> Workstation on vlan 1

Can't ping 10.0.1.1 ---> Sonicwall router
Can't ping wwww.google.com

On Vlan 1 I can ping all of the above with no issues at all.

Configured laptop IP: ip: 10.0.2.251 won't ping.

When I try to ping 10.0.1.1 from vlan 2 its a no go
When I try to ping 10.0.1.252 ----> DHCP Server from vlan 2 its also a no go.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your gateway will need to be on the same network as your host (laptop gateway is listed as 10.0.2.1).

Are all these devices plugged into a switch that is then plugged into the Sonicwall?  Or do you have two different zones setup on the Sonicwall and two different uplinks from the switch?

Comment: Finny: The gateway 10.0.2.1 is the Ip address for my vlan 2.  I was told that if your are in vlan 2 use 10.0.2.1 as my default gateway, so i can communicate to the other vlans on the network namely my vlan 1.  the sonicwall is plugged into my hp 2920 switch which spiders out my connections to my data pc / ip phones.  I can ping any pc inside of any vlan if the gateways are set to 10.0.2.1 (Can ping any device on both vlans except my server and firewall ) and 10.0.1.210 ( Primary vlan - Pcs communicate to internet as well as with other devices on vlan 2) respective of the vlan it is in.